# Was World War 1 a direct consequence of the Balkan Wars?

Tags: world-war-one, the-balkans

The Wikipedia article for [Balkan Wars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balkan_Wars) lists it as one of the reasons leading to WW1. Otto von Bismark also quoted

> If there is ever another war in Europe, it will come out of some damned silly thing in the Balkans

Is it correct to conclude that the WW1 was essentially an extension of the Balkan Wars?

Comment: I suspect that WW1 would have happened anyway, it would just have been triggered by something else. There was too much political tension between the European powers for it to just fade away.

Comment: Events in the Balkans were more of a *casus belli* than the principle reason. There were many clashes of interest besides this small area - it is for a reason that it is called a *World* war (not a Balkan war, and even not a "Great European war".)

Comment: I'm sure there was an ostrich involved.

Comment: I'm sure there was an Österreich involved.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. It was a war that was bound to happen. It just started in the Balkans. Even that was an accident: yes, [archduke Franz Ferdinand](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Franz-Ferdinand-Archduke-of-Austria-Este) was killed, but in the **second** attempt. During the first attempt [Gavril Prinzip](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Gavrilo-Princip) was present, but not able to act. Others threw a bomb that bounced of and exploded under the next car. Gavril walked away, and got a sandwich.

In the mean time, Franz Ferdinand was - understandably - furious. He was calmed down and persuaded to continue his visit. His driver had not been informed of the change in route, made a wrong turn and had to back up and reverse. Right in front of the shop where Prinzip got his sandwich. He didn't hesitate for a second, and killed the archduke and his wife.

That was something nobody could have planned.

The war might have begun a lot earlier, for example between England and France over the [Fashoda Incident](https://www.britannica.com/event/Fashoda-Incident). Or between France - England vs Germany during the [Panther Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agadir_Crisis).

It just happened to be the killing of a rather unpopular heir to the throne. When the crisis developed, even the German emperor thought it was not worth cutting his holiday short for.